# Tab Bar Controller with Drawer in iOS

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, swift2, mmdrawercontroller

I am new in ios.I want to implement the tabbar and drawer in same application.For drawer i use MMDrawerController.My problem is that tabBar in view controller is not shown after implement the drawer.My storyboured image is:[image]
When i open the drawer and select any row then after in centerviewcontroller is not shown the tabbar.
Output screenhsot is like:

[image] [image: aftercategory select]

Here After select the category from leftContainer in second screenshot( Center container) tabBar is not shown.
 And in leftContainer tabBar is also not show.
How can i improve and what is the change?.

Answer (score 0):

There could be 3 possibilities check
1.While pushing view controller there might be used this property

```
viewControllerObject.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES; //set NO
```

2.If subclass from other view controller then in superclass check(in viewDidLoad)

```
self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;//Set NO
```

3.Also in Interface builder (Just Uncheck it)

You have to set to "NO"

Comment: hidesBottomBarWhenPushed  is alredy set the No.any change in navigation controller .may be segue problem.But i don't know what the problem .If u find out from storybourd

Comment: hidesBottomBarWhenPushed could be set to YES in library check in MMDrawerController library